# setting onclicklistener to numberpicker dynammicaly added android

Tags: android, dynamic, event-listener

I have the following situation:

When the app start i show an prompt dialog in which the user can say how many different tickets they want. If they fill in 3 there comes another dialog where they can fill in an description and a price for the tickets.

That part work, but when I want to add eventlistener to the numberpicker so when they click + or - it calcutlates the right price for te ticket.

[image]

Like u can see on the image, there are 5 textviews and 1 number picker that are added dynamically.

I've tried the following but that doesn't work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < differentTickets; i++){
        final int j = i;
        NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) findViewById(j+10);
        np.setOnNumberPickerChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnNumberPickerChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNumberPickerChanged(NumberPicker mynumberpicker) {
                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(j+100);
                tv.setText("test");

            }
        });
    }
```

This is the code how I add the views dynamically:

```
for (int i = 0; i < differentTickets; i++) {
                                ticket t = new ticket();
                                t.setOmschrijving(omschrijvingenLijst
                                        .get(i).getText().toString());
                                t.setPrijs(Double.parseDouble(prijzenLijst
                                        .get(i).getText().toString()));
                                ticketten.add(t);

                                LinearLayout llTicketsH = new LinearLayout(
                                        MainActivity.this);
                                llTicketsH
                                        .setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

                                TextView tvv = new TextView(
                                        MainActivity.this);
                                tvv.setText(omschrijvingenLijst.get(i)
                                        .getText().toString());
                                tvv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                                tvv.setTextSize(
                                        TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 30);
                                tvv.setWidth((int) convertDpToPixel(400,
                                        MainActivity.this));

                                llTicketsH.addView(tvv);

                                TextView tvPrijs = new TextView(
                                        MainActivity.this);
                                tvPrijs.setText(prijzenLijst.get(i)
                                        .getText().toString());
                                tvPrijs.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                                tvPrijs.setTextSize(
                                        TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 30);
                                tvPrijs.setWidth((int) convertDpToPixel(
                                        100, MainActivity.this));
                                tvPrijs.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                                tvPrijs.setId(i);
                                llTicketsH.addView(tvPrijs);

                                TextView tvEuro2 = new TextView(
                                        MainActivity.this);
                                tvEuro2.setText(" €");
                                tvEuro2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                                tvEuro2.setTextSize(
                                        TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 30);
                                tvEuro2.setWidth((int) convertDpToPixel(50,
                                        MainActivity.this));
                                llTicketsH.addView(tvEuro2);

                                NumberPicker np = new NumberPicker(
                                        MainActivity.this, null);
                                np.setId(i+10);
                                llTicketsH.addView(np);

                                TextView tvPrijsTot = new TextView(
                                        MainActivity.this);
                                tvPrijsTot.setText("xxx");
                                tvPrijsTot.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                                tvPrijsTot.setTextSize(
                                        TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 30);
                                tvPrijsTot.setWidth((int) convertDpToPixel(
                                        100, MainActivity.this));
                                tvPrijsTot.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                                tvPrijsTot.setId(i+100);
                                llTicketsH.addView(tvPrijsTot);

                                TextView tvEuro = new TextView(
                                        MainActivity.this);
                                tvEuro.setText(" €");
                                tvEuro.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                                tvEuro.setTextSize(
                                        TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 30);
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams MOs = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                                tvEuro.setLayoutParams(MOs);
                                llTicketsH.addView(tvEuro);

                                llTickets.addView(llTicketsH);

                            }

                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is `getParent` of `NumberPicker`... Then in that parentView get the textView with `childPosition` in that View to update as per your requirement...

Like this..

```
for (int i = 0; i < differentTickets; i++){
        final int j = i;
        NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) findViewById(j+10);
        np.setOnNumberPickerChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnNumberPickerChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNumberPickerChanged(NumberPicker mynumberpicker) {
                //TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(j+100);
                LinearLayout parView = (LinearLayout) mynumberpicker.getParent();
                TextView tv = parView.getChildAt(5);//your child view at position
                tv.setText("test");

            }
        });
    }
```